# Add +1 to cell, to be the highest value in range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table looking like this

```
A | B 
=====
a | 1
b | 2
c | 3
```

I am looking for an easy way (Script / Button / whatever), to increment the values in B by 1, but always using the highes value as base. 
So for example, when i use the button on B1, it should become 4. If I then use it on B2, it should become 5 and so on

I hope someone understand :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: find the highest in B, put in variable as the highest +1, iterate the rows of B, if it is numeric, put the variable value and variable +=1, and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `Apps Script`.

### Step by step guide:

1. `Insert Drawing` to your sheet, its your `button`
2. Create next `script` and save :

```js
function updateValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var column = ss.getColumn();
  var maxValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(1, column, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .sort(function(a,b){
      return b-a
    })[0][0];  

  ss.setValue(ss.getValue() + maxValue);
  // ss.setValue(1 + maxValue);
}
```

3. Click on Assign script to your Drawing(button) and type updateValue

### What is the procedure to work the button?

1. Select cell with value
2. Click your button
3. It will find the highest value in column and sum it to the current cell value

Before the button click :
[image]
After the button click:
[image]

### Reference

- [Apps Script - Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Apps Script - Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: This helped a lot, chaning the last line in the script to ss.setValue(1 + maxValue); is exactly what i needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jayrrr I glad to hear that from you. If you find this answer correct, please accept it and upvote